# How to prevent commit to a vector layer during editin session in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, editing, pyqgis-3

I am writing a plugin that listens to editing events, such as the `QgsVectorLayer.editingStarted`, `QgsVectorLayer.geometryChanged` signals. So far all is fine but there are also some validation rules that should be applied at the end of the editing session and commit should be prevented if they fail. The commit should not go through and the editing session and edit buffer should stay unaffected.

On the C++ side, I can call `QgsVectorLayer::setAllowCommit()` from within the `beforeCommitChanges()` slot but this is not available from Python, as the [QGIS documentation specifically says](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a6006c3fa637fa2b5ff7d14677a90ca2d). Is there some workaround that can be used from PyQGIS to get the same effect?

I tried raising exception from `beforeCommitChanges()` but this still proceeds with the commit. Subclassing `QgsVectorLayer` and overriding `commitChanges()` does not help either as I suspect the commit is triggered from C++ and it does not go through Python at all?

Comment: You're right. In my opinion, the best way to proceed is to either create an [issue](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues) or ask in the [QGIS-dev mailing list](https://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer), to discuss if there is a reason for not offering this method in the Python bindings. It might be your opportunity to get involved into QGIS core.

Comment: Did you solve this somehow?